# clangのdump結果をファイルに保存する方法

Tags: c, ubuntu, clang

お世話になります。

clangをインストールしたubuntu上で、適当なC言語のプログラムに対して以下のコマンドを実行すると、コマンドライン上に字句解析結果が表示されます。

```
clang -cc1 -dump-tokens test.c
```

このとき表示される字句解析結果をファイルに自動で保存する方法はありませんでしょうか？
以下のコマンドは試しましたが、空のファイルが生成されるだけになっていまいます。

```
clang -cc1 -dump-tokens test.c > test.txt
```

以上です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clang`コマンドの実行結果は恐らく**標準エラー**に出力されていると思うので、リダイレクトは`>`の代わりに`>&`を使用してみてください。

```
$ clang -cc1 -dump-tokens test.c >& test.txt
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事にファイルに出力できました！